# Get response from server with a custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement the following: Have a custom class(so i can call/use it from many parts of my app) where with the help of `AFNetworking`,i request to the server and get the response.
My code inside the class works,but when i call it from other parts of my app,i am getting a null value. I believe it because of my custom class.Anyway here is my code:

**UDIDGen.h**

```
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
@interface NSString (UDIDGen)
+ (NSString *)getUDID;
@end
```

**UDIDGen.m**

```
#import "UDIDGen.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

@implementation NSString (UDIDGen)

+ (NSString *)getUDID{
    __strong __block NSString *holder;

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/id.php"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:@"http://domain.com/id.php"
                                                      parameters:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        holder=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSLog(@"SERVER RESPONSE: %@",holder);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    }];
    [operation start];
    return holder;
}
@end
```

And then when i want to call it from other parts of my app i

```
#import "UDIDGen.h"
```

and then

```
 NSString *wsa=[NSString getUDID];
 NSLog(@"Response %@",wsa);
```

For some reasong `NSLog(@"SERVER RESPONSE: %@",holder);` works and i am able to nslog the server response. But `NSString *wsa=[NSString getUDID];` gives me null value.
I believe it has to do with the way i am implementing my custom class, i am doing something wrong.
Any help?

**EDIT**:My working code so other will use it:

**UDIDGen.h**

```
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
@interface UDIDGen:NSObject{

}
- (void)getUDIDWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *udid))completion;
@end
```

**UDIDGen.m**

```
#import "UDIDGen.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

@implementation UDIDGen

- (void)getUDIDWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *udid))completion {
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/id.php"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:@"http://domain.com/id.php"
                                                      parameters:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *udid=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"SERVER RESPONSE: %@",udid);
        if (completion)
        {
            completion(udid);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //  TODO: Handle error
    }];
    [operation start];
}
@end
```

Use it like this:

```
UDIDGen *getResponse = [[UDIDGen alloc] init];

    [getResponse getUDIDWithCompletion:^(NSString *udid) {
        NSLog(@"SERVER RESPONSE: %@",udid);
    }];
```

Comment: Actually blocks were implement in Asynchronous way, So, that when you returned the holder object by calling the getUDID method, by that time the value for that holder object is not assigned. So, just  try to return the value in success block. just return from the NSLog  line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` asynchronously. This means it's running in a separate non-blocking thread, and your method might return before the request has finished.

The easiest way would be to just do this, but this will most likely block the GUI while loading:

```
[operation startSynchronous];
```

The cleanest way would be to use a completion block or delegate yourself and inform the target class when a response has been received:

```
+ (void)getUDIDWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *udid))completion {
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/id.php"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:@"http://domain.com/id.php"
                                                      parameters:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *udid=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"SERVER RESPONSE: %@",udid);
        if (completion)
        {
            completion(udid);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //  TODO: Handle error
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

You would call this method like so:

```
[YourCustomClass getUDIDWithCompletion:^(NSString *udid) {
   // use udid / update GUI
}];
```

Comment: Well [operation waitUntilFinished] blocked my GUI.Any sample code?Any reference?

Comment: @Theodoros80 I've added an example.